# c# Mongdb.Dynamic Method Missing Exception with upsert()

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, orm

I am writing an asp.net MVC4 Application. I have a couple of DAO interfaces and DTO classes, and want to insert instances of these classes into my mongo database.

I tried the following in a console application and it works :

```
Dynamic.Config.SetKeyName<IInventorySystem>(i => i.Id);
        Dynamic.Config.SetIndex<IInventorySystem>("idx_invSystem", false, i => i.Name);
        Dynamic.Config.SetKeyName<IContainer>(c => c.Id);
        Dynamic.Config.SetIndex<IContainer>("idx_Container", false, i => i.Name);
        Dynamic.Config.LoadCollection<IInventorySystem,IContainer>(i=>i.Containers,c=>c.InventorySystemId);
        Dynamic.Config.LoadFK<IContainer,IInventorySystem>(c=>c.InventorySystem,c=>c.InventorySystemId);
        Dynamic.Configure();
        var invSystems = Dynamic.GetCollection<IInventorySystem>();
        var containers = Dynamic.GetCollection<IContainer>();
        var invSystem = invSystems.New();
        invSystem.Name = "bla";
        invSystems.Upsert(invSystem);
```

However the same code in an MVC Controller doesnt work, I revieve the following error:

```
"Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.SafeModeResult MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1.Insert(System.__Canon)'."}
```

**Unsuccessful approaches taken to further isolate the problem**

- Instantiating the DAO and hardcoding the values of its properties, to eliminate problems that may have been caused by binding from the html form.
- Using impromptuInterface to generate a proxy and then setting its properties before saving the proxy, to eliminate the DTO being the issue
  See: http://mongodbdynamic.codeplex.com/documentation
- Adding Dependancy injection to the project as opposed to using a static object for the DatabaseContext, to prevent garbage collection / threading issues which could occur since the MVC App works differently to the single thread console application.

**Connection to the DB**
Works. Collections created, but I cannot save in the mvc4 application.

**Research**

In my research I have found many missing method issues, but none related to mongodb.dynamic
Similar problems can be found looking for issues with the mongodb c# driver but these are also not quite the same

*Why MongoDB and not a relational DB?* Because I want to add a dictionary of key value pairs to a certain DTO later. But it would be nice to get the basics going first.

So finally thanks for reading to the end, any help would be greatly appreciated, or a different aproach with mongo that is mvc compatible.

**Version information**

MongoDb.Dynamic (installed with nuget) - Version 1.1.1
MongoDb Official C# Driver (intalled with nuget) Version 1.10.0

Comment: What version of MongoDB dynamic are you using, and what version of the MongoDB driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks for having a look - I added the versioning information you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB.Dynamic hasn't been updated in ~3 years. It is depending on an older version of the driver. The mongocsharpdriver does not use semver in its 1.x series, so using the 1.10 version of the driver doesn't have the methods in it that are being used by MongoDB.Dynamic.